# How to use $in with a Regular Expression with Pymongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to aggregate a collection in mongodb based on $in which tries to get the aggregate data from all the documents whose Log_Dir contains '/route_sanity/' in it somewhere in the path.
Surprisingly this query doesnot works with pymongo. {please note that I am taking 'version by the user}

```
pipeline=[    
   { '$match': { 'cgdvo_version' : version,'Dut_Name':'yvm','Log_Dir':{ '$in': ['/route_sanity/'] } } },
   { '$group': {          
    '_id':               
        'jid',         
    'PassVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Pass']}, 1, 0]} },
    'FailVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Fail']}, 1, 0]} },
    'ErrorVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Error']}, 1, 0]} },
    'TotalVEVO': { '$sum': 1 }
} }, 
   {'$project':{'FailVEVO':1, 'PassVEVO':1,'ErrorVEVO':1,'TotalVEVO':1,'_id':0}}]
res= smokedb.command('aggregate','jid',pipeline=pipeline)
```

To cross check ,the following query works fine in robomongo (mongodb client)

```
db.getCollection('jid').find({cgdvo_version : 'pub-20150614.2',Dut_Name:'yvm',Log_Dir:{ $in: [/route_sanity/] }})
```

Please help!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes around the regular expression, which means it is being interpreted as a string. If in doubt to your language syntax, use the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) BSON operation instead. But here just use [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
pipeline=[    
   { '$match': { 
       'cgdvo_version' : version,
       'Dut_Name':'yvm',
       'Log_Dir':{ 
           '$in': [re.compile('/route_sanity/')] 
       }
   }},
   { '$group': {          
    '_id':               
        'jid',         
    'PassVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Pass']}, 1, 0]} },
    'FailVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Fail']}, 1, 0]} },
    'ErrorVEVO': { '$sum': { '$cond' :  [{ '$eq' : ['$Result', 'Error']}, 1, 0]} },
    'TotalVEVO': { '$sum': 1 }
   }}, 
   {'$project':{'FailVEVO':1, 'PassVEVO':1,'ErrorVEVO':1,'TotalVEVO':1,'_id':0}}
]
```

Otherwise:

```
   { '$match': { 
       'cgdvo_version' : version,
       'Dut_Name':'yvm',
       '$or':[{ 'Log_Dir': { '$regex': 'route_sanity' }}]
   }},
```

Or since they are regular expressions, with more than one possible match then just use the OR `|` operation there

```
   { '$match': { 
       'cgdvo_version' : version,
       'Dut_Name':'yvm',
       'Log_Dir': { '$regex': 'route_sanity|something_else' }
   }},
```

And that obviates the need for either [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) or [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Also note that you presently only have one condition. These methods allow you to specify multiple conditions with regular expressions. But if you only need one then just do:

```
   { '$match': { 
       'cgdvo_version' : version,
       'Dut_Name':'yvm',
       'Log_Dir': { '$regex': 'route_sanity' }
   }},
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But either of the case didnot work for me. :(